# C code won't run on windows (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c, visual-studio

My program works fine on Linux running on GCC, however when I compile and run the code on Windows using Visual Studio 2013 it gives me this error : Unhandled exception at 0x00EC2527 in a3a3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00692000).

It also inserts a breakpoint into crtexe.c at line 626; here are lines 624 - 626 for reference:

```
#else  /* WPRFLAG */
            __initenv = envp;
            mainret = main(argc, argv, envp);
```

I have compiled and ran C programs before using Visual Studio 2013, but this one doesn't seem to want to work and I cannot for the life of me determine why. I would greatly appreciate your help, I'm fairly new to programming and this is my first post on stackoverflow. I would as well appreciate any extra tips or criticism to help me learn. Thank you.

Here is my program : http://pastebin.com/X731mU7W

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be great if you could try to reduce your code to the relevant parts, and then include these in your question. Just linking to code should be avoided. While trimming the code, you might even discover the problem's cause! :)

Comment: @lethal-guitar Thanks for the pointer. I only included the entire code because I had no clue which area of the code was being affected.

Comment: I admit that it can be difficult to narrow down the code when your program crashes before `main`. This is usually a strong indication that you're trying to push something huge onto the stack of main or you're trying to allocate some global data that's just too big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`struct CR CRArray[14500]` is too big to live on the stack (hence the Stack Overflow). Dynamically allocate it instead.

```
struct CR *CRArray = malloc (sizeof (struct CR) * 14500);
```

Although, because it's VS, you probably need to cast the return of `malloc` in this instance.

Also, don't forget to `free` the memory.

Comment: Thank you so much! The program runs fine now.

Comment: Whether a cast is necessary depends on the file's extension. Only if it's `.c`, VS will actually compile it as C code (instead of C++), and then no cast is needed.

Comment: You saved my hell lot of time! thanks @anthony-arnold